# Mounting Problems

Tags: mount

I'm running PopOS and, after a recent clean install, I'm having some problems with a secondary HDD I use for data storage.

***My Partitions***
One disk /dev/**sda1** "data" is a 1Tb hdd NTFS logical partition for Basic Data. It is mounted as /mnt/data
One disk /dev/**sdb1** is a 500Gb ssd with multiple partitions:

- 1Gb FAT32 /boot/efi /dev/sdb1
- 17Mb Microsoft reserved thing /dev/sdb2
- 150Gb NTFS win10 system
- 4Gb swap /dev/sdb4
- 105Gb ext4 /home  /dev/sdb5
- 251Gb ext4 / (my popOS root)  /dev/sdb7
- 523Mb Microsoft recovery thing /dev/sdb6

This way my system and apps are in /.
My /home is separate and independent.
And I dump pretty much all my files and downloads in the external drive "data".

Data is mounted like so:
UUID=70D48E04D48DCD32
/mnt/data
ntfs
rw,auto,user,exec,noatime,errors=remount-ro,nofail,x-gvfs-show
0
0

It seems to work ok, except...

***Problems***

First, I can't trash files. I only have the option to **permanently delete** them (which on my Nautilus is set to NOT be available, btw).

Second, my browser saves downloads wrong.
Edge/Opera/Chrome always ask me where to download files even though I set a default directory and toggled off the option to always prompt me for action.
Looking into it, I noticed that while I set the download directory as **/mnt/data/myName/Downloads** the browsers interpret it instead as this weird thing **/run/user/1000/doc/a0207089/Downloads**

Interestingly, **Firefox** doesn't show this behavior and does everything as expected.

I assume the two problems might be related.
How can I fix them?

This is my fstab:

```
PARTUUID=c262783b-5cf0-47cc-aaa2-c1ca59b38cd6  /boot/efi  vfat  umask=0077  0  0

/dev/mapper/cryptswap  none  swap  defaults  0  0
    
UUID=492f3857-56c4-44a7-ba34-2145fc8c8048  /home  ext4  noatime,errors=remount-ro  0 0

UUID=ba17cb87-0f71-41e2-97a2-4ccc889ead63  /  ext4  noatime,errors=remount-ro  0  1

UUID=70D48E04D48DCD32 /mnt/data ntfs rw,auto,user,exec,noatime,errors=remount-ro,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

Comment: You must make sure Windows fast startup stays off. That sets hibernation flag on all NTFS partitions. It often is turned back on with updates which you may not see. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1436555/grub-cannot-boot-windows-error-not-a-valid-root-device I have seen this as mount options for NTFS: `windows_names,nosuid,noatime,async,big_writes,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0113,dmask=0022` The big_writes mount option does help performance greatly. Supposed big-writes now default? May depend on distribution.  https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NTFS-3G windows_names to insure only valid chars used.

Comment: Fast Startup is off.

Adding the fstab options you mentioned helped with the "can't trash bin" problem. Thanks! :D

But the browser(s) still behave weirdly.